# Strongly typed language for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, i2c, software-development, pwm

I would like to know if there is a matrix somewhere that list the languages that could be used on a Raspberry Pi.

I've a broad experience in C# and a not to bad knowledge of Java.

For my first weeks of tests, I used Python. I can think of many advantages of python, but I don't like how we declare class, the fact that it's not strongly typed, and some other things.

So I was thinking to use another language, or at least give it a try, but I don't find a "compatibility" list of languages.

I was interessted in Java, but I was told that the library that has to be used (`PI4J`) was not supporting the 1Wire protocol by example.

Currently, the protocol/interface that I would need are:

- GPIO IN/OUT
- PWM
- I2C
- 1Wire protocol

Additionally, I would like a language which allow me to:

- Language oriented object
- Language allowing to have an IDE with auto completion

What language could you advise me? I know that C++ is an option, but I was always happy to have a garbage collector ;)

I'm currently using raspbian, but open to change if you need

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for this site.  Debian and therefore Raspbian probably provide all the programming languages you have ever heard of and then dozens more.

Comment: How can it be too broad if there only 2-3 languages that fits those needs?

Comment: Joan's right; this is a series of unrelated questions glued together, and it invites a bunch of *different* answers.   Since your problem with python is *subjective* (I'm not a fan either), it would make more sense for you to come up your own list of languages that you do like, then narrow it down on the basis of which required libraries and tools are available.

Comment: Linux provides a language agnostic GPIO interface, but there are also pi-specific libraries which have additional functionality.  If you need that, "Is there a pi-specific GPIO library for language X that can ______?" is a fair question here; "Is there an I2C library?" belongs on Stack Overflow -- but that is easy to check online, so you probably want to ask a more detailed question.   If you plan to program directly on the pi, "Is IDE X feasible on the pi?" (a lot of them are not, even though they are technically available) is also a fair question.

Comment: Ok, so I will end by creating one topic for each language and technology that I'm thinking of?

Comment: Pi support was recently added to Xojo, a RAD IDE with a strongly-typed, object-oriented programming language. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1):

You can install nodejs on Pi and use javascript.

Comment: I don't know very much NodeJs, but I do know javascript. But as far I know, it's not strongly typed, can do object but is not object oriented. Is there something I missed? Why do you think it fits my needs?

Comment: Sorry, missed OO. Was to concentrated on garbage collection. I'm not using OO, so I can't be sure to recomend solution.